# How do I print out the elements that is in both tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

```
a = (('we', 23), ('b', 2))
b = (('we', 3), ('e', 3), ('b', 4))

#wanted_result = (('we', 3), ('b', 4), ('we', 23), ('b', 2))
```

How can I receive the tuple that contains the same string in both `a` and `b`
like the result I have written below the code?
I would prefer using list comprehensions using filters btw... would that be available?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Why is using a list comprehension relevant at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can use set intersection:

```
keys = dict(a).keys() & dict(b)
tuple(t for t in a + b if t[0] in keys)
```

Comment: Instead of creating the tuple again every iteration using `t[0]` should be less expensive and more readable correct?

Comment: Less expensive I think yes, more readable might depend on the reader :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a set of the intersection between the first part of the tuples in both lists.  Then use a list comprehension to extract the tuples that match this common set:

```
a = (('we', 23), ('b', 2))

b = (('we', 3), ('e', 3), ('b', 4))

common = set(next(zip(*a))) & set(next(zip(*b)))
result = [t for t in a+b if t[0] in common]

[('we', 23), ('b', 2), ('we', 3), ('b', 4)]
```

You can also do something similar using the Counter class from collections (by filtering tuples on string counts greater than 1:

```
from collections import Counter
common = Counter(next(zip(*a,*b)))
result = [(s,n) for (s,n) in a+b if common[s]>1]
```

If you want a single list comprehension, given that your tuples have exactly two values, you can pair each one with a dictionary formed form the other and use the dictionary as a filter mechanism:

```
result = [t for d,tl in [(dict(b),a),(dict(a),b)] for t in tl if t[0] in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding two list comprehensions (i.e. concatenating lists):

```
print([bi for bi in b if any(bi[0]==i[0] for i in a)] + 
  [ai for ai in a if any(ai[0]==i[0] for i in b)])
# Output: [('we', 3), ('b', 4), ('we', 23), ('b', 2)]
```

**Explanation**

```
[bi for bi in b if any(bi[0]==i[0] for i in a)] # ->>
# Take tuples from b whose first element equals one of the
# first elements of a

[ai for ai in a if ai[0] in [i[0] for i in b]]
# Similarly take tuples from a whose first elements equals one of the 
# first elements of b
```

Answer (score 1):

another variation with sets

```
filtered_keys=set(k for k,v in a)&set(k for k,v in b)
res=tuple((k, v) for k, v in [*a, *b] if k in filtered_keys)
>>> (('we', 23), ('b', 2), ('we', 3), ('b', 4))
```